# Svelte for VS Code: How to avoid the formatter from removing double quotes in attributes?

Tags: svelte, vscode-extensions

I'm using [Svelte for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=svelte.svelte-vscode) extension.

Currently when formatting it removes double quotes in HTML attributes

Example:

```html
export let altText;
<img src="test.jpg" alt="{altText}" />
```

when formatted it turns it into something like this

```html
export let altText;
<img src="test.jpg" alt={altText} />
```

Which is totally valid. However, I want to keep the quotes in the attributes. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I do not recommend this, it is essentially just visual noise. Also, the semantics are weird, it looks like a string interpolation but it actually retains the type if there is no other text.

Answer (score 1):

The extension uses [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) (which is annoying). You might be able to configure this by adding a `.prettierrc` and setting the [`quoteProps` option](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#quote-props) to `"preserve"`.

**Edit**: Tested this, and it is currently *not* respected.

---

The plugin for Svelte has an option for setting a [strict mode](https://github.com/sveltejs/prettier-plugin-svelte#svelte-strict-mode), either via the VS settings:

```json
{
    "svelte.plugin.svelte.format.config.svelteStrictMode": true
}
```

Or via the `.prettierrc` (the VS setting is ignored if the file exists):

```json
{
    "svelteStrictMode": true
}
```

This will preserve the quotes but also kill shorthands, so e.g. from

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let alt: string;
</script>

<img src="test.jpg" {alt} />
```

To

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let alt: string;
</script>

<img src="test.jpg" alt="{alt}" />
```